# MS SQL Server '08 ignoring username and password when requesting a connection with connection string using Integrated security=SSPI

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I'm using this connection string to connect to a ms sql server '08 db,

```
"Data Source=qwe;Initial Catalog=dsa;Integrated Security=SSPI;User Id=mydom\unamee;Password=pwd;"
```

but the server is ignoring the username i specify and uses my machine name instead; and says that it is unable to authenticate user `mydom\myMachineName`
I've check the other similar question, but that is not the same as this problem, someone please help, my head is breaking

Comment: If you want to use `User ID=..` then you need to **remove** the `Integrated Security=SSPI` from your connection string; **either** you use integrated security (using the current credentials), ***OR*** you want to define user id and password - but not **both** at the same time!

Comment: If you have a username and password for another *domain* account (rather than an SQL user account), then you'd need to perform *impersonation* within your code and then use Integrated Security - you can't pass domain login credentials across in the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `Integrated Security=SSPI` (or `true`), `UserID` and `password` you have specified are ignored. Login will be made using the windows credentials you are logged in Windows\domain. In that case you'll need to have an appropriate  windows login created in SQL Server.

If you want to use SQL Server login, specifying username and password created in SQL Server -you should set '`Integrated Security=false` or remove that property altogether because `false` is default value.

**EDIT:**

To make a long story short: You can **either** use Integrated security or username/password and not both. You can not log in using someone else's domain account, only of user logged in Windows at the moment.

Comment: thanks man, but now it's saying login failed for my domain user. . ?

Comment: Check with your DB Admin whatever your domain user have credentials to login.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use a domain account to connect to Sql Server you have to be logged with that account, Integrated Security=SSPI; pass to SQL the current domain credentials,User Id and Password values in connection string are used to send SQL Server user (not domain user) and password to connect to it, but in this case your Sql Server has to be set in mixed mode security to allow this kind of credentials. Sorry about my english, I hope this was useful for you. Regards